# Continuous Integration pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking to trigger the on_failure step in my pipeline. I have a very simple script.
2 resources and 1 job. The job has a run step in which I would like to trigger failure manually. I have tried many things and they all leaded to an error.

Is there an shell script exit code that could make the task to fail and not being errored

Comment: With "_on\_failure step_" do you mean the [`post` section's `failure` condition](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions)?

Comment: yes,  I do you mean the post section's failure condition?

Answer (score 0):

Triggering [`post` → `failure`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions) and not failing the build is not possible:

> `failure`
>
> Only run the steps in `post` if the current Pipeline’s or stage’s run has a "failed" status, typically denoted by red in the web UI.

However, you can do the following:

```groovy
def status

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Failing stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    status = sh script: 'exit 99', returnStatus: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always {
            script {
                if ( status == 99 )
                    echo 'Script failed...'
                else
                    echo 'Script succeeded...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example post -> failure

```
     post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
        success {
            sendEmail('SUCCESSFUL')
        }
        unstable {
            sendEmail('UNSTABLE')
        }
        failure {
            sendEmail('FAILED')
        }
    }
```